# ListView in Preference

Tags: java, android, listview, preference

I've created a custon preference screen for my Android application (Honeycomb), that contains a ListView.

```
public class XXXPreferences extends Preference
{
    @Override
    protected View onCreateView(ViewGroup parent)
    {
          ListView...
    }
}
```

Everyting is shown as expected, but the ListView is not scrolling. It seems that it is because the Preference class has a build in ScrollView and the ListView does not supported to be embedded in a ScrollView.

So I would like to know if it is possible to remove the ScollView of the Preference class or if there is another trick to make things work !?

Thanks in advance for your response :)
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

If the preference class has a scrollview, you shouldn't need your ListView.   Just use a vertical LinearLayout and add your layouts to that as needed.

Comment: Hello,Thanks for your answer. I finally manage to solve this by using the solution proposed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495890/ Probably not the best way but at least it's working :)